# Actulizar tabla con condición

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una **TABLA** con campos: *id*, *cant* y *cuota*.
Los campos *id* y *cant*, tienen valores.
La clase recibe dos parámetros: *$valor* y *$max*
Quiero actualizar el campo ***cuota*** según la condición.

```
public function calcular($valor, $max) {
    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE TABLA SET cuota = IF(cant >= :max, :max * :valor, cant * :valor)";

        $bd = new ConexionDB();
        $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':valor', $valor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
```

Pero no ejecuta el el *try*.

Comment: Prueba a imprimir detras del execute, print_r($bd->errorInfo());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema aquí es que quieres re-utilizar marcadores de `:nombre`, lo cual no está permitido.

[La documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) es bastante clara al respecto (las negritas son mías):

> Se debe incluir un único marcador de parámetro para cada valor que se
> desee pasar a la sentencia cuando se llame a `PDOStatement::execute()`.
> **No se puede usar un marcador de parámetro con nombre con el mismo nombre más de una vez en una sentencia preparada, a menos que el modo
> de emulación esté activado**.

**ADVERTENCIA:** No actives el modo de emulación para permitir re-utilizar marcadores. Con la emulación activada te pueden colar *Inyección SQL* creyendo que tus consultas preparadas son seguras.

Para resolver esto, simplemente **usa marcadores distintos**, aunque los valores que les pases sean los mismos. Debes tener en cuenta que el *quid* de la cuestión de cara a la *inyección SQL* es impedir que te cuelen código malicioso **por medio de los valores que el usuario proporciona**, es por eso que al usar consultas preparadas lo que hace PDO y las otras APIs es: 1. Preparar la consulta poniendo **marcadores** en vez de los valores; 2. Enviar los valores aparte, para verificar si nada malicioso hay en ellos.

Así debería funcionar:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE TABLA SET cuota = IF(cant >= :maxA, :maxB * :valorA, cant * :valorB)";

    $bd = new ConexionDB();
    $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':valorA', $valor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':valorB', $valor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':maxA', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':maxB', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;
```